# How to read GAP's output on "IrreducibleRepresentations"?

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory, finite-fields, gap

For example for the group $SL_2(\mathbb{F}_3)$ I get the following,

```
gap> IrreducibleRepresentations(SL(2,3));
[ CompositionMapping( [ (4,5,6)(7,9,8), (2,7,3,4)(5,8,9,6) ] ->
[ [ [ 1 ] ], [ [ 1 ] ] ], <action isomorphism> ),
  CompositionMapping( [ (4,5,6)(7,9,8), (2,7,3,4)(5,8,9,6) ] ->
[ [ [ E(3)^2 ] ], [ [ 1 ] ] ], <action isomorphism> ),
  CompositionMapping( [ (4,5,6)(7,9,8), (2,7,3,4)(5,8,9,6) ] ->
[ [ [ E(3) ] ], [ [ 1 ] ] ], <action isomorphism> ),
  CompositionMapping( [ (4,5,6)(7,9,8), (2,7,3,4)(5,8,9,6) ] ->
[ [ [ E(3), -E(3) ], [ 0, E(3)^2 ] ], [ [ E(3), 1 ], [ E(3), -E(3) ] ]
 ], <action isomorphism> ),
  CompositionMapping( [ (4,5,6)(7,9,8), (2,7,3,4)(5,8,9,6) ] ->
[ [ [ E(3)^2, E(3) ], [ 0, 1 ] ],
  [ [ -E(3)^2, -E(3) ], [ -E(3), E(3)^2 ] ] ], <action isomorphism> ),
  CompositionMapping( [ (4,5,6)(7,9,8), (2,7,3,4)(5,8,9,6) ] ->
[ [ [ E(3), E(3)^2 ], [ 0, 1 ] ], [ [ 0, 1 ], [ -1, 0 ] ]
 ], <action isomorphism> ),
  CompositionMapping( [ (4,5,6)(7,9,8), (2,7,3,4)(5,8,9,6) ] ->
[ [ [ 0, 0, 1 ], [ 0, 1, 0 ], [ -1, -1, -1 ] ],
  [ [ 0, 1, 0 ], [ 1, 0, 0 ], [ -1, -1, -1 ] ] ], <action isomorphism> ) ]
```

It seems to me that it is specifying the two matrices in in each irrep of $SL_2(\mathbb{F}_3)$ which correspond to the two elements which it denotes as $(4,5,6)(7,9,8)$ and $(2,7,3,4)(5,8,9,6)$. But I don't know what is its scheme of denoting of denoting the group elements are? (what group elements do these two pairs of tuples correspond to?) And how to get the matrix for every group element from this?

Comment: I don't know if this is correct, so I am not listing this as an answer.  But...it appears to me that $(4, 5, 6)(7, 9, 8)$ and $(2, 7, 3, 4)(5, 8, 9, 6)$ are the *generators* of $SL_2(3)$, which it is somehow internally (and now externally) storing as a permutation group.  I'd *guess*, therefore, that these permutations correspond to the generators of $SL_2(3)$ as matrices, which you can view if you call `GeneratorsOfGroup(SL(2,3));`.  As slight confirmation, you can note that the group orders of these two matrices are 3 and 4: call `List(GeneratorsOfGroup(SL(2,3)), Order);`.

Comment: "GeneratorsOfGroup(SL(2,3))" is not a command on GAP

Comment: List(GeneratorsOfGroup(SL(2,3)));
[ [ [ Z(3)^0, Z(3)^0 ], [ 0*Z(3), Z(3)^0 ] ], [ [ 0*Z(3), Z(3)^0 ], [ Z(3), 0*Z(3) ] ] ]

Comment: Are you sure?  It works absolutely fine for me (without the quotation marks, and with a semicolon).  I'm using GAP 4.6.2, so you may have a different version.

Comment: How does one map this above list to which of these two permutations it might correspond to?

Comment: OK, you found the generators.  What you have is a list of lists.  The first one is [ [ Z(3)^0, Z(3)^0 ], [ 0*Z(3), Z(3)^0 ] ], so let's look at that one first.  This is a matrix; it's showing you the first row of your 2-by-2 matrix, [ Z(3)^0, Z(3)^0 ], followed by the second row, [ 0*Z(3), Z(3)^0 ].  This corresponds to a first row of (1, 1), and a second row of (0, 1), if I have read it correctly (as an element of $\mathbb{F}_3$, that is).

Comment: Anyway, I am not sure about this; you'll need to do more investigation with these elements.  But I'm guessing that these two matrices in your list correspond to the two permutations we saw.

Comment: (1) What is the mapping from these 2x2 matrices to the permutations that GAP uses to represent them? (2) And How to get the matrices for all the 24 elements in the group?

Comment: For your second question, just type `Elements(SL(2,3));`.  For your first question, again, I am not sure, but I am *guessing* that the first of those two matrices corresponds to the first of your permutations, and the second to the second.  At the very least, we can see that the orders are correct (3 for the first one, and 4 for the second, just like with the permutations).  Beyond that, I can't help you further.  Best of luck!

Comment: This "Elements(SL(2,3))" command only seems to give a list of the group elements. But to be able to put to use this irrep data one needs to know how each of these elements decompose into a product of the generators "(4,5,6)(7,9,8)" and "(2,7,3,4)(5,8,9,6)". Does GAP give that?

Comment: Yes, GAP does allow you to write group elements in terms of the group generators.... One way is to use the functions `EpimorphismFromFreeGroup` and `PreImagesRepresentative`.  See http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap39.html for examples.  Good luck!

Comment: Pasting the GAP output in the question, please indent it by four spaces, like I've just done in my edit. Then it will look like above, and now the reader may see `<action isomorphism>` which was not visible before. In this example, each representation is a composition of two mappings: `<action isomorphism>` which maps $SL(2,3)$ onto an isomorphic permutation group, and then the matrix representation.

Answer (score 3):

What GAP returns is a list of homomorphisms, i.e. the actual irreducible representations. Each of these homomorphisms is a bit more complicated, as it actually factors from SL(2,3) through an isomorphic permutation group. What you can do is to take any such homomorphism, and evaluate it at arbitrary elements of SL(2,3).

```
gap> G:=SL(2,3);;
gap> irr:=IrreducibleRepresentations(G);
[ CompositionMapping( [ (4,5,6)(7,9,8), (2,7,3,4)(5,8,9,6) ] -> 
    [ [ [ 1 ] ], [ [ 1 ] ] ], <action isomorphism> ), [...]

gap> rep:=irr[6];
CompositionMapping( [ (4,5,6)(7,9,8), (2,7,3,4)(5,8,9,6) ] -> 
 [ [ [ -E(3)^2, -E(3) ], [ 1, 0 ] ], [ [ 0, 1 ], [ -1, 0 ] ] ],
 <action isomorphism> )
gap> mat:=[[1,0],[1,1]]*One(GF(3));
[ [ Z(3)^0, 0*Z(3) ], [ Z(3)^0, Z(3)^0 ] ]
gap> Image(rep,mat);
[ [ -E(3), E(3)^2 ], [ -1, 0 ] ]
```

i.e. this group element is mapped to $\left(\begin{array}{cc}-\zeta&\zeta^2\\
-1&0\end{array}\right)$ where $\zeta=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}$.

If you want to see what happens with generators under all representations, you could use:

```
gap> gens:=GeneratorsOfGroup(G);
[ [ [ Z(3)^0, Z(3)^0 ], [ 0*Z(3), Z(3)^0 ] ], 
  [ [ 0*Z(3), Z(3)^0 ], [ Z(3), 0*Z(3) ] ] ]
gap> List(irr,r->List(gens,g->Image(r,g)));
[ [ [ [ 1 ] ], [ [ 1 ] ] ], [ [ [ E(3)^2 ] ], [ [ 1 ] ] ], 
  [ [ [ E(3) ] ], [ [ 1 ] ] ], 
  [ [ [ E(3), -E(3)^2 ], [ 0, E(3)^2 ] ], 
      [ [ -E(3)^2, 1 ], [ E(3)^2, E(3)^2 ] ] ], 
  [ [ [ E(3)^2, -E(3) ], [ 0, 1 ] ], [ [ E(3), E(3)^2 ], [ E(3)^2, -E(3) ] ] ]
    , [ [ [ -E(3)^2, -E(3) ], [ 1, 0 ] ], [ [ 0, 1 ], [ -1, 0 ] ] ], 
  [ [ [ -1, -1, -1 ], [ 0, 1, 0 ], [ 1, 0, 0 ] ], 
      [ [ 0, 1, 0 ], [ 1, 0, 0 ], [ -1, -1, -1 ] ] ] ]
```

Comment: What is the isomorphism map that GAP uses from elements of SL_2(F_p) to S_p^2 ? It clearly has one in mind when it chose to represent the generators as permutations!

Comment: The Isomorphism is stored as `NiceMonomorphism(G)`, though generically one also could use `IsomorphismPermGroup`. In this particular case it is simply the action on nonzero vectors.

Comment: This is not clear. What is this E(3) ? If 0 is occurring in the generators that GAP is using then it is having F_3 in the additive representation which has elements (0,1,-1) and there is no clear meaning to E(3). What is permutation representation that GAP is using to write its generators in a cycle decomposed notation?

Comment: @user6818 E(3) is explained in my answer (it is $\zeta$), and the permutation action is on vectors. I have difficulties parsing the rest of your comment.

Comment: This interpretation of E(3) or Z(3) doesn't make sense. Firstly is E(3) the same as Z(3) ? I think there are two natural ways to think of F_p,

- as the set {0,1,2,3..,p-1}

- or as the set {0,1,x,x^2,...,x^{p-2}}

where x is the (p-1)^th primitive root of unity

Now what is GAP thinking when it says that [[0,1],[Z(3),0]] is one its generators of SL_2(F_3)?

F_3 can either be represented in {0,1,-1} or as {0,1,2}

What is Z(3) or E(3) ?

Comment: $Z(3)$ is not the same as $E(3)$ -- the former is a primitive root in the finite field with 3 elements, the latter is a complex number, exactly as Alexander explained. Both are described  in the GAP manual and easy to find with the builtin help system. I recommend looking at that first for some time.

Comment: Do you understand what I am trying to say? Its not clear as to in which representation of F_3 is it possible for 0, 1 and a primitive root of unity to occur together! Why is GAP shifting from the Z(3) that it uses in the generators to the E(3) that it uses later?

Comment: This is classical representation theory, i.e. the representations GAP returns are over the complex numbers, not over a finite field. Hence a primitive third root of unity occurs in the final representation.

Comment: @Max Its not that clear. When one is asking for " IrreducibleRepresentations(SL(2,3))" it makes sense that the matrices it returns are over the complex field as thats where the representations are. Then GAP uses something called E(3) which I believe is the primitive cuberoot of unity. But when one is asking for List(GeneratorsOfGroup(SL(2,3))); what is this Z(3) that GAP is using?  When one is listing out the generators of SL(2,3) the matrices should be 2x2 matrices with entries in F_3.

Comment: $Z(p^d)$ is a generator of the multiplicative group of the finite field if order $p^d$. For $p^d=3$, if one were to model the field as $Z/3Z$, it'd be the coset $2+3Z$. Once more I refer you to the GAP help system and manual, where all this is readily explained .

Comment: Can you kindly give the link to where in the manual this is explained? In the manual I can't even find an index to see what is the meaning of Z(3) !

Comment: In the manual chapter on finite fields: http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap59.html#X7893ABF67A028802   The representation used might seem nonintuitive at the start -- the reason behind it is efficiency of operations, compatibility of different field extensions and (using Zech-Logarithms) the need to only store $O(n)$ numbers for the addition table than naively $O(n^2)$.